# Eclipse CDT Neon.2 and latest MSYS2 GDB

Tags: eclipse, gdb, msys2

I would like to use MSYS2 and mingw64 for C/C++ Development on Windows 7. I use a batch for that.

```
SET MINGW_HOME=c:\msys64\mingw64
SET MSYS_HOME=c:\msys64\usr
SET PATH=%MINGW_HOME%\bin;%MSYS_HOME%;%PATH%
start eclipse.exe
```

I am able to build projects in eclipse and I also can run them but debugging does not work.